# How to check and undo custom access denied page in 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, customization, access-denied

Here's an odd one.  I have a site with about 18 site collections under the main web application, each with their own content database. My account should give me full access to everything.

There's two site collections that are giving me an access denied error.  But that's not the only weird part.  The sites appear to be trying to go to a custom access denied page which doesn't exist on this site, so I get a 404 error over and above the access denied error.

[image: Sitename obscured for obvious reasons]

It gets weirder - the other site collections on the site don't point to the same custom page. I changed some permissions to a different collection, and when I tried to access it, I got the default access denied.

So there's a couple of things about these two collections that don't seem to be in phase with the rest of the site, but I'll only worry about this custom page issue here. Everything I've found suggests that one can't set up a custom error page for only one site collection, so I'm at a loss as to how these are odd men out.

I *think* what I need to know is:

How can I check what the current page the site is using for the access denied error?

How can I undo a custom access page?  I've found the commands to set one via powershell, but I haven't seen how to go back to the default.

Of course, the other way to attack it is to add a collection at that spot and load the page, but I'd rather get it all back to the default first.

I'm rather surprised there's no way to do it via the UI, since it seems like a fairly common thing people would want to do. You can do it in IIS fairly easily.

Anyway, there's every chance this is only one symptom of a larger issue, but I'm hoping if I can at least get this layer of the issue sorted, it'll help.

Anyone? Anyone? Beuller?

Comment: 1. By what method has your account been granted access to everything? 2. Have you tried running Fiddler or any other diagnostic tool (even Internet Explorer's network tab in F12 developer tools) to see what happens traffic-wise when you navigate to the two site collections in question? 3. Can you navigate directly to the All Site Content pages of those sites ( [site url]/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx ) instead of navigating to their homepages?

Comment: You really should be good permission-wise, then. In that case my first guess would be that there's a JavaScript redirect or something similar embedded in the homepages or masterpages of those sites. The answers to questions 2 and 3 in my comment above should help you determine whether that's the case. You might also try editing the sites in SharePoint Designer.

Comment: I didn't want to mix up the access denied issue itself with the specific issue with the custom error page here, but here's that information:

1) My account has full control permissions set both in user policies, set both from Central Admin and at the web application level on the web

2) I have run a Fiddler, and it's showing some odd things - it's looking for the list services in the wrong spot - vt32bin instead of _vti_bin. Investigating that with Microsoft.

3) I get the same error trying the viewlists page.

Comment: Sorry, first comment got goofed up - re-posted.

I can only get to the pages in Designer via the site's extended address, which uses window authentication - the main address uses claims based (via siteminder), which I only just realized I neglected to mention in the initial post. Guess it would helped, huh?

I can access everything using windows auth, including the two exception collections. It's only via the "front door" (Claims based) that they fail.

But as I say, I want to try and sort the custom error page issue here, just to get one thing out of the way

Comment: Intriguing! So you can get to the sites just fine with the extended address? If you try to hit something that you don't have access to on those site collections using the extended address, do you get the normal Access Denied page, or does it still try to redirect you to the nonexistent custom one?

Comment: I tried that - I shut off permissions (for other users) for another collection, and that collection returns the normal access denied page. And I'm buffaloed how they can have different custom pages.  This is why I'm trying to clear that - one less discrepancy.

Comment: That at least suggests that the custom access denied page is not configured within SharePoint anywhere, but that it might be coming from the authentication provider. With that in mind, the only other thing you might want to double check is Central Admin -> Security -> Specify Authentication Providers -> Choose the web application containing the sites in question -> Edit authentication -> "Sign In Page URL"

Comment: Just to provide closure, it turned out the issue was on the proxy server that SiteMinder uses - the permissions for the two sites were not properly set up, so the site was never accessed. And indeed, the link for the accessdenied page was coming from that site as well, hence the non-existent call.  Thanks for the help, regardless.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out! You should go ahead and post that as a self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

Already posted as a comment, but just to provide closure, it turned out the issue was on the proxy server that SiteMinder uses - the permissions for the two sites were not properly set up, so the site was never accessed. And indeed, the link for the accessdenied page was coming from that site as well, hence the non-existent call.